# How to share family pictures using Google Photos, Drive and Picasa?

Tags: shared-folders, google-drive, picasa, google-photos

Google released a great app called Google Photos this year, which also enables you to store/backup your pictures using a dedicated folder in Google Drive.

Nearly all pictures are family pictures, so I would like to share ownership of the pictures with my wife. What is the best way to do that? We both use Drive, Google Photos, and Picasa, but I can't find a straightforward way to do this. When I share my dedicated Google Photos folder in Drive, it does not appear as a dedicated folder in her Drive, just as a shared folder. She has her own Google Drive folder.

The objective is that both of us can access, manage and edit pictures using Picasa. If possible, they should also appear in Google Photos.

Answer (score 1):

It seems we'll have to wait until the end of this year:
*By the end of the year, you'll be able to invite friends and family to contribute to your photo albums.*
source: http://www.theverge.com/2015/9/29/9411439/google-photos-update-2015-chromecast-support